# Delayed Job Not Sending Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, delayed-job

Delayed Job is not sending emails on my Rails App.

Documentation says in order to have email sent properly, I should change

```
Mailer.some_email(args).deliver
```

to

```
Mailer.delay.some_email(args)
```

which I have done, but email is still not sending properly. I'm running Rails 3.2.6, delayed_job 4.0.0, and delayed_job_active_record 4.0.0.

I ran the delayed job with another action (created basic record in database), and it worked properly, so normal jobs are being queued and executed properly. It just looks like it's having trouble with Mailers.

Comment: check if any error in the database table generated by delayed job, to send the email.

Comment: In which environment you're testing it?